# Mobile-friendly menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

The menu problem is on the mobile version, for the desktop it works fine.
In the mobile version the menu works, but when I go on one page and scroll down, anywhere I press on the left side redirects me to another page in the menu. Exactly where displays the menu page when it is open.

I mention that I have a menu with three lines and after entering a page click on X and the menu disappears, only that instead of pages if I click directs me to other pages on the site.

How to solve it?

```
<div class="center-container">
  <div class="w3_agile_header">
    <div class="w3_agileits_logo">
      <div class="w3_menu">
        <div class="agileits_w3layouts_banner_info">


        </div>
        <div class="mobile-nav-button">
          <div class="mobile-nav-button__line"></div>
          <div class="mobile-nav-button__line"></div>
          <div class="mobile-nav-button__line"></div>
        </div>
        <nav class="mobile-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://ioanasandu.ro/online/web/index.html" >Despre mine</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://ioanasandu.ro/online/web/repertoriu.html">Repertoriu</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://ioanasandu.ro/online/web/discografie.html">Discografie</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://ioanasandu.ro/online/web/evenimente.html">Evenimente</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://ioanasandu.ro/online/web/foto.html">Foto</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://ioanasandu.ro/online/web/video.html">Video</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://ioanasandu.ro/online/web/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow.. Please provide enough code that the entire problem can be reproduced entirely on someone's local machine so that the problem can be looked at... currently your code is missing CSS and some HTML.  It doesn't have to be the entire web page, just enough to reproduce the area with the issues . Take a look at [ask] for more on helping us help yuou

Comment: There is also a button on the editor itself that allows for the inclusion of HTML /CSS / Javascript Snippets which can help to keep things organized (its the button with the <> icon)

Comment: Also take a look at [repro] to learn how to [edit] your question to make it easier for people to answer it.